# Angular 6 make http use https

Tags: angular

So, my app is being served by a simple web server, under "https://localhost:8443/app", while the same web server returns json responses under eg. "https://localhost:8443/api/login".

TLS is set up with a self signed certificate for now.

when I request the app, I get the certificate warning, which I skip, and then I see my login page.

on clicking the login button, the angular application executes

```
http.post<LoginResponse>('/api/login', body)
```

which shows up in my browsers network trace as a post request to
"http://localhost:8443/api/login".

I cannot find any info on this, only infos on how to handle tls when running the app with angular-cli.

Why does the app default to http, and where do I tell it to use https?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http), they have an example where they use an interceptor to ensure https. The code snippet below is taken from their documentation:

```
// clone request and replace 'http://' with 'https://' at the same time
const secureReq = req.clone({
url: req.url.replace('http://', 'https://')
});
// send the cloned, "secure" request to the next handler.
return next.handle(secureReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using https instead of http should be enough in angular 5+. Just make sure your server is properly configured for https and you are using the right https port. If you get "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID", put the troublesome link in the browser. When your access is prohibited, click on advanced, and then continue with unsafe access. This is only for testing on  your local machine.